# at and daylight saving time

Tags: linux, at

Suppose I have added a task via `at -t` specifying the next day in my timezone.
The next day my timezone changes as of daylight saving time. The question is whether the task will be executed correctly at expected time.

Comment: This question is old, but I'm interested in the answer too. I have always scheduled tasks using a shell script that parses the time given and then uses `GNU sleep`. The problem is that this week the daylight savings time changed, and sleep was there totally stuck for hours.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior Using `sleep` doesn't survive a system reboot. `at` jobs do get started, even if the system was down at the time the job was originally scheduled.

Comment: @Anthon No, I didn't mention a reboot, but rather I seem to have found some bug in `sleep`. If you run something like `sleep 1h`, and then the clock changes (it was reproducible with the daylight savings time changing, but also seems to happen after system suspend/hibernation), sleep keeps running for hours and hours, and never seems to finish. I ended up writing my own implementation of `at`, supporting `sleep` and `date` style arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will execute correctly at the given time, which is the time you will see on your wall clock (assuming you corrected it for DST).

The only "problem" times are within the actual hour that gets "lost" when the DST starts and the clocks are move forward. In that case **at the time of scheduling** an extra 3600 seconds are added to that start time (DST changes in western Europe in 2017 on March 26th):

```
$ at 02:30 2017-03-26 
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> echo hallo
at> <EOT>
job 10 at Sun Mar 26 03:30:00 2017
$ at 03:31 2017-03-26 
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> echo hallo
at> <EOT>
job 11 at Sun Mar 26 03:31:00 2017
```

You can check these with `atq`:

```
11  Sun Mar 26 03:31:00 2017 a anthon
10  Sun Mar 26 03:30:00 2017 a anthon
```

Although the input was 61 minutes apart, the scheduled tasks are only 1 minute apart.